Show/hide one element at the time
I using this script to show/hide content. However, how can I close open elements when opening one?
I tried with something like this, but it's not working correctly:
// Get siblings
var contentSiblings = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

// close them before opening new one
if (contentSiblings) {
        contentSiblings.forEach((elem) => {
                if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
                        hide(elem);
                }
        });
}



// Show/hide filter content
var show = function (elem) {
    elem.classList.add('is-visible');
};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);
};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
.content {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

.content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
<a class="btn" id="btn-one" href="#one">Button one</a>
<a class="btn" id="btn-two" href="#two">Button two</a>
<div class="content" id="one">Content one</div>
<div class="content" id="two">Content two</div>




You can add a function hideAllElements to hide all visible elements before show content:


// Show/hide filter content
function show(elem) {
    hideAllElements()
    
    elem.classList.add('is-visible');
};

// Hide an element
function hide (elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
};

// Hide all elements
function hideAllElements (elem) {
    const visibleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.is-visible');
    for (const element of visibleElements) {
        element.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }
};

// Toggle element visibility
function toggle (elem) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);
};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    
    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected content
    const content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
.content {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

.content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
<a class="btn" id="btn-one" href="#one">Button one</a>
<a class="btn" id="btn-two" href="#two">Button two</a>
<div class="content" id="one">Content one</div>
<div class="content" id="two">Content two</div>



On a side note, if you give descriptive names to your functions, the comments are not needed anymore.

Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it.

Exactly, thank you so much.

you can also do:


document.body.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('.btn')) return;
  
  if ( document.body.className === e.target.id )
    document.body.className = '';
  else  
    document.body.className = e.target.id;
  })
.content {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

body.btn-one #one.content ,
body.btn-two #two.content { 
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  }
<a class="btn" id="btn-one" href="#">Button one</a>
<a class="btn" id="btn-two" href="#">Button two</a>
<div class="content" id="one">Content one</div>
<div class="content" id="two">Content two</div>




Probably a simple approach would just be to always hide all "content" elements before showing one.  For example, the show function can first hide all elements and then show the specified element:


// Show/hide filter content
var show = function (elem) {
    // Hide all others first
    document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(hide);

    elem.classList.add('is-visible');
};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);
};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
.content {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

.content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
<a class="btn" id="btn-one" href="#one">Button one</a>
<a class="btn" id="btn-two" href="#two">Button two</a>
<div class="content" id="one">Content one</div>
<div class="content" id="two">Content two</div>




With a little CSS; flex box layout, next-sibling combinator, and :has(), you can show and hide elements using radio buttons.


section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section label {
  order: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: start;
}

section label:has(input:checked) {
  background: PowderBlue;
}

section label:has(input:checked)+div {
  display: block;
}

section input {
  display: none;
}

section div {
  order: 2;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid black thin;
  min-height: 5em;
}
<section>
  <label><input type="radio" name="tab" checked>Button one</label>
  <div class="content">Content one</div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="tab">Button two</label>
  <div class="content">Content two</div>
</section>



